# How to fetch contact details from Contacts and display it in a textview?

Tags: android

I want to fetch contact details from Contacts and display it in a textview. I tried with the below code, but my application gets crashed. I'm a beginner in android and I'm not able to identify the mistake.Can anyone help me..
Here's the code:
                                   /*MainActivity.java*/

```
package com.example.retrievecontacts;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView txtv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewContacts);
        readContacts();

    }

    public void readContacts() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("......Contact Details.....");
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        String name = null;
        String id = null;
        String phone = null;
        String emailContact = null;
        String emailType = null;
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phone = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone);
                    System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();
                Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    emailContact = emailCur
                            .getString(emailCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    emailType = emailCur
                            .getString(emailCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                    sb.append("\nEmail:" + emailContact + "Email type:"
                            + emailType);
                    System.out.println("Email " + emailContact
                            + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                }
                emailCur.close();
            }
            sb.append("\n........................................");

        }
        txtv.setText(sb);
    }

}

                              /*activity.xml*/

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.retrievecontacts.MainActivity" >
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/viewContacts"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I also wrote the permission in the manifest as:

Then whats the problem. Why my application gets crashed?

Comment: can you please share your logcat entries here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot move cursor to first position:

```
cur.moveToFirst();
```

your code must be like:

```
 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
             .......
             .......
```

if this not helped you post your logcat error.

I think you must get `CursorIndexOutOfBoundException`

you need check `pCur` too,

```
if (pCur.getCount() > 0) {
                pCur.moveToFirst();
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                  .......
                  .......
```

and `emailCur` and all cursor that you have

one another problem that you have is **Manish Mulimani's** said in bellow answer, so read that too

change your code with:

```
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                                           // do your job 

                    } while (cur.moveToNext());
```

Comment: I added that line..But still my application gets crashed

Comment: ur rite..M getting, cursor out of bound exception:04-14 05:59:20.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4

Comment: I added for all..But still its crashing

Comment: M getting cursor index out of bound exception

Comment: post all logcat that we say line number of error, and put if statement into `while`

Comment: The mistake was: I had put if condition outside the while loop..But there is no need to check,whether count is greater than 0, for all cursor. In the beginning we are checking that condition. Now it worked for me..Thanks for the help

Comment: I have one more query. I added 4 contacts but its displaying only 3

Comment: which one not displaying? first one or last?

Comment: @sangeetha you should consider accepting **Manish Mulimani's** answer above as that's the appropriate answer that solved your problem...

Comment: last one is not displaying

Comment: Manish Mulimani and shayan poutvatan's answers helped me. But Shayan is helping me from a long time.So I accepted his answer

Comment: If i add do while loop it gets crashed

Comment: did you check size of cursor too?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan that was by mistake ...but the answer here is not what solved the problem actually ...do you agree to that,...? as commmented by user its the answer given by Manish Mulimani that actuallly solved the problem...so future readers should not be misguided by accepting this as answer

Comment: @sangeetha `Shayan is helping me from a long time` that should not be the reason to accept any answer on **SO** .....  you can always upvote the answers that helped you but should only mark the answer that is correct one or it will mislead the future readers so please do so...

Comment: @y.dixit i think both answer is complete each other, if OP don't use `moveToStart()` give `arrayIndextOut`

Comment: Okay..I got correct now..But its enough if we add do while at the beginning. i.e., if(cur.moveToFirst());
   do {....}while();                             It Works

Comment: @shayanpourvatan thats an additional this but according to the comment of OP here it suggests that the actual answer that helped to solve the problem is Manish Mulimani's....surely your efforts and help deserves up vote....but think from the mind set of future readers....

Comment: @y.dixit. Even after Manish Mulimani's answer, my output was incomplete. It was not displaying all contacts. So It gives partial output. Now I got the correct answer. So According to that I should accept  shaman pourvatan's answer rite?

Comment: @y.dixit i UPvote manish answer and edit my post for future reader

Answer (score 2):

If loop is placed outside while loop as shown below. So while loop exits when cursor is past last entry in the data set and hence it crashes when accessed in if block. Place the if statement inside the while loop.

```
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
```

Comment: Still it gets crashed

Comment: Look at the while loop. The if loop is not included in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code to display all contact names and numbers stored in device in list view....try it...it works...

**Activity which shows the name and number in list view...**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> nameNumberMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String contactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        nameNumberMap.put("Name",contactName);
        nameNumberMap.put("Number",contactNumber);
        al.add(nameNumberMap);

    }

    Log.e("check","as2");
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, al);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.e("check","as2"+al.size());



}
}
```

**Custom Adapter class**

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public customAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al) {
    Log.e("check", "");
    activity = a;
    this.al = al;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return al.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Number);

    HashMap<String, String> contains = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contains = al.get(position);
    Log.e("value check:----", contains.get("Name"));
    name.setText(contains.get("Name"));
    number.setText(contains.get("Number"));
    return vi;
}

}
```

**XML for first activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML for row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >


    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it's better to solve OP's problem instead of giving complete code.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Yes agreed.... for that I have asked for log cat entries....so if any specific error exists will be happy to solve it and have put the working code for reference purpose...